# CSS div is not placed at the right side of parent

Tags: html, css, css-float

As the title says I want to place a div right inside another div. However when placing it on the right side it completly ignores its parent.

```css
.cart {
  /* Distance to the items in the cart and the Checkout button*/
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  /*Restrict size*/
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  /*Center of the page*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*distance to bottom of page*/
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  /*Debugging*/
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}

.cart-price {
  /*make button decrease size into its center*/
  text-align: center;
  width: fit-content;
  justify-self: flex-end;
}


/* Display of total price*/

.cart-price-summary {
  /*TODO style text*/
}

.cart-checkout-button {
  /*style*/
  background-color: #2B2E32;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 2.5em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  font-family: "Palatino Regular";
  font-size: 1em;
  /*remove white border*/
  border: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="cart-price">
  <b class="cart-price-summary">Total: € 194.50</b><br>
  <button class="cart-checkout-button">Checkout</button>
</div>
```

This is how the div should be placed (except it should be on the right hand side).
[It should be like this but on the right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEk0L.png)

When getting the div on the right side (by float: right;) and a few other ways i have tried it seems to be positioned outside of the parent div and ignoring its given distance to the bottom of the side. [The div on the right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GX9sE.png)

Answer (score 3):

```css
.cart {
  /* Distance to the items in the cart and the Checkout button*/
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  /*Restrict size*/
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  /*Center of the page*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*distance to bottom of page*/
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  /*Debugging*/
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}

.cart-price {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   align-items: flex-end;
}


/* Display of total price*/

.cart-price-summary {
  /*TODO style text*/
}

.cart-checkout-button {
  /*style*/
  background-color: #2B2E32;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 2.5em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  font-family: "Palatino Regular";
  font-size: 1em;
  /*remove white border*/
  border: 0px;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="cart-price">
  <b class="cart-price-summary">Total: € 194.50</b><br>
  <button class="cart-checkout-button">Checkout</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

first, you have to delete   `justify-self: flex-end;`,  because you are not using flexbox,
second thing wrap up the card in another div tag, this div will take 100% of the width,
now you can add `flaot: right;` to .cart-price.

html file:

```
<div>
        <div class="cart-price">
            <b class="cart-price-summary">Total: € 194.50</b><br>
            <button class="cart-checkout-button">Checkout</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

and the css file should be like:

```
.cart-price {
    /*make button decrease size into its center*/
    text-align: center;
    width: fit-content;
    /* justify-self: flex-end; */
    float: right;
  }
```

Comment: I did exactly that but it unfortunatly does the same:/

Comment: that is what I did exactly, and the cart-price goes to the right, 
check if you added the wrapper <div> 
you can add more HTML code to give us a better idea about the bug you have

Answer (score 0):

So I just fixed it.
i rewrote the whole thing to use flexbox and added `justify-content: right;` to `.cart`
so now the .cart is fixed in the middle of the page but the content is on the right side. which is no problem for everything else in the .cart section but the button is now on the right side.